# Argument "points" in the quad function of python

Tags: python, scipy, integral

I want to do a principal integral using the `scipy.integrate.quad` function in Python's `scipy` package. For example, I want to calculate (sorry for the latex codes):

```
\begin{equation}
\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}
\left(\int_{-1}^{-\epsilon}dx\frac{1}{x}+\int_\epsilon^1 dx\frac{1}{x}\right)
\end{equation}
```

or

[image: equation]

I found from the manual that there is an optional argument of `quad`, `points`, which is a sequence of break points in the bounded integration interval where local difficulties of the integrand may occur. Can `points` be used to calculate the expression above? If so, how exactly should I implement it?

Comment: _"...quad function of python."_ - I'm not familiar with any builtin "quad" function in Python. Could you elaborate on this?

Comment: I meant scipy.integrate.quad

Comment: `scipy.integrate.quad` can handle integrable singularities. Is it the case of your function? The limit in the expression is not something that SciPy in itself can solve in your place.

Comment: No, that singularity is not integrable, that is why I used principal integral as defined in the latex code

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the `weight` parameter to select the weighting function. For the integral you wrote,

```
In [15]: quad(lambda x: 1, -2, 3, weight='cauchy', wvar=0)
Out[15]: (0.4054651081081642, 0.0)

In [16]: log(3./2.)
Out[16]: 0.4054651081081644
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19275657/python-find-principal-value-of-an-integral-numerically) if your integrand is of the form `g(x)=f(x)/(x-x0)` you can indeed use `weight='cauchy'`. Be sure to pass `f` as the integrand, not the quotient. Obviously, if your integrand is not of this form you could try multiplying it by (x-x0).

`quad` uses [QUADPACK's](https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/f_src/quadpack/quadpack.html) `QAWCE` routine which is a dedicated solver for Cauchy principal values.

You could probably also try and integrate `g(x0+x') + g(x0-x')` where `x0` is your singularity and mark `x'=0` as a difficult value. (If the integration limits are not symmetric around `x0` you have to integrate the excess separately.) This is probably not better than the specialist `QAWCE` but you never know til you have tried.